# Get "SIGN.MEDIA"-Id for compatibility-mode in Windows7

Tags: windows-registry, compatibility

i try to set the compatibility mode in Windows7 in my C# project.
Normaly, it is no problem: Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers   and add a new REG_SZ. Name = Path (C:\test.exe), Data=WINXPSP3 (for WindowsXP SP3 compatibility)..

The Problem comes with CD/DVD. There you can't set the path with the Driveletter, but you have to set "SIGN.MEDIA=1234567" for example instead of "F:\".

Is there a way to get the SIGN.MEDIA-ID? Because it changes with every ISO-File i create and burn.

thank you

Comment: is there an other way, to set the compatibility mode for an executable on my CD/DVD?

Comment: Why do you change compatibility mode on a medium that you create? Do you want to set compatibility mode to software you deliver?

Comment: I seemed to have the same question. But now I'm observing changing `SIGN.MEDIA` values for the same USB memory stick when setting compatibility modes to programs in different folders, I proved this to be true for CD/DVD media as well. I think the question should be rephrased.

Answer (score 0):

Define an environment variable before launching your application. For example in batch:

```
SET "__COMPAT_LAYER=WINXPSP3"
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) needs to be expanded.  Please edit it to explain *why* your solution addresses the OPs question.